# Restarting a linux app using a respawn entry in inittab does not work

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, fedora, init.d, inittab

**Scenario:**
I have a process running on linux which is started in the background by a script hooked up at `/etc/init.d/` called as `MyApp` which is just a shell script without the `.sh`. Following is my `init.d` script script

```
#!/bin/sh

PARAM=$1

case ${PARAM} in
    start)
        MyApp &
        ;;
    stop)
        killall -9 MyApp
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

As you can see it starts `MyApp` in the background.

**Objective and problem:**
I want to restart `MyApp` when it crashes. I tried to find out how that is done. Looks like I have to add an entry into `/etc/inittab` from various links I read. So I added the following entry into `/etc/inittab`.

```
MyApp:12345:respawn:MyApp
```

**Question:**
Above does not seem to work and how can I get this to work correctly? What is the wrong that I am doing here?

**Note:**
I am doing a `killall -9 MyApp` and expeciting it to restart because of the entry I added to `/etc/inittab`. Is this expectation correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case ${PARAM} in
    start)
        (while :; do MyApp ;done) &
        ;;
```

Comment: @xDragonZ this might be an answer, despite a description is missing.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes rather late, but your unique ID in the line you wrote is 5 characters. The maximum lenght for the ID must be 4.